# Using GIO in Python 3

Tags: python, gvfs

How can I access the [`gio`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIO_%28GNOME%29) module for Python 3.2? (I want to interface with GVFS.) I did

```
sudo apt-get install python3-gobject
```

but this does not allow me to do

```
import gio
```

as it did in Python 2.7. Is the GIO module not provided with GObject in Python 3? How do I access it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`gio` is a PyGTK module, and is not available for Python 3 because PyGTK itself is deprecated. If you want to create a GTK+ application in Python 3, you will need to use its replacement: [PyGObject](http://live.gnome.org/PyGObject). In the case of Gio, you import it like this.

```
$ python3
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  5 2011, 21:17:14) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gi.repository import Gio
```

Such documentation as exists can be found [here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/python-gtk-3-tutorial/en/latest/index.html). Best of luck!

Answer (score -3):

It appears to be renamed to 'gi':

```
$ python3
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  5 2011, 22:09:30)
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
>>>
```

See the file listing of the python3-gobject package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/i386/python3-gobject/filelist

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. See @Jacob's answer for the correct import.